# Pass filter and sort parameters in query string HTTP request and parse with Flask

Tags: http, query-string, flask-restful

I'm developing a REST api with Flask.
One of my endpoints should support filtering and sorting.
lets say i have these fields: category, color, severity.

Lets say i want to get all the items that category is 'a'or 'b' and the color is black and sort it by the severiy asc and color desc.

for the sorting i saw that prepending '+' or '-' is a way to set the order.

**1.What is the best practice to decode the filter expression? assuming i want to use a query string method for passing parameters in get request (or the best option is to use a json-body parameters for this need)**

**2. What is the best way to parse it in flask framework?**

my_ip/items?sort=+severity&sort=-color&filter=???

Answer (score 4):

This article give some good suggestions on how to approach it: [Pagination, Filtering, and Sorting](https://specs.openstack.org/openstack/api-wg/guidelines/pagination_filter_sort.html)

> For example:
>
> - Only sort keys specified:
>
>   - `sort=key1,key2,key3`
>   - `key1` is the first key, `key2` is the second key, etc.
> - Sort directions are defaulted by the server
> - Some sort directions specified:
>
>   - `sort=key1:asc,key2,key3`
>   - Any sort key without a corresponding direction is defaulted
>   - `key1` is the first key (ascending order), `key2` is the second key (direction defaulted by the server), etc.
> - Equal number of sort keys and directions specified:
>
>   - `sort=key1:asc,key2:desc,key3:asc`
>   - Each key is paired with the corresponding direction
>   - `key1` is the first key (ascending order), `key2` is the second key (descending order), etc.